# Best way to format JSON

Tags: jsx

I've been given some data (random example shown below) and I would like to format it into the following (with different example to random example but same format): 
EDIT:

The numbers in both format and example do not represent each other.

```
export const formatted = [
    {date: "hone: 30},
    {date: "20/6,
  ];
```

I can only think of using map() inefficiently with loops. But is there any better way to automatically do this filtering?

```
export const unformatted = [
        {_string: "20t: 1,
               00000,
                    doc_cs: {
                        value: 1902
                    }
                }
            ]
            }
```

This is just a learning experience and I'm only wanting to learn and provide layouts of how to format given data properly in JS React.

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. What properties should be on `formatted` based on `unformatted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `reduce` and one `find` seem to do it. I defined cars/phones as separate objects to speed this up. Let me know if this helps. It should not be very difficult to get them same result from the array form you posted. Let me know if things will get you going or I missed something.

```js
var cars = {
 key: "car",
 doc_count: 26,
 sales_over_time: {
  buckets: [
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-20",
    key: 1532088000000,
    doc_count: 1,
    total_sales: {
     value: 3850
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-21",
    key: 1532174400000,
    doc_count: 1,
    total_sales: {
     value: 260
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-22",
    key: 1532260800000,
    doc_count: 3,
    total_sales: {
     value: 0
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-23",
    key: 1532347200000,
    doc_count: 1,
    total_sales: {
     value: 933
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-24",
    key: 1532433600000,
    doc_count: 2,
    total_sales: {
     value: 1902
    }
   }
  ]
 }
};
var phones = {
 key: "phone",
 doc_count: 26,
 sales_over_time: {
  buckets: [
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-20",
    key: 1532088000000,
    doc_count: 1,
    total_sales: {
     value: 4678
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-21",
    key: 1532174400000,
    doc_count: 1,
    total_sales: {
     value: 2445
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-22",
    key: 1532260800000,
    doc_count: 3,
    total_sales: {
     value: 833
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-23",
    key: 1532347200000,
    doc_count: 1,
    total_sales: {
     value: 139
    }
   },
   {
    key_as_string: "2018-07-24",
    key: 1532433600000,
    doc_count: 2,
    total_sales: {
     value: 1102
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}

var result = cars.sales_over_time.buckets.reduce((result, value, index, array) => { 
  var phoneObj = phones.sales_over_time.buckets.find(phone => phone.key === value.key)
 result.push({
 date: value.key_as_string,
 car: value.total_sales.value,
 phone: phoneObj ? phoneObj.total_sales.value : 'N/A',
})
 return result
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is perfect for the format. I never assumed to create two variables which separated both distinguishing keys. Just a question: Is this good practice for some given data? If so, this makes everything much more appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: Well it depends on the definition of `good practice`. I do not know much about your data domain other than it seems to be coming from Elastic Search but if you know that the results for cars/phones would always be the same count that it is much easier. Since we do not know that we have to traverse one of them and for each item find/cross reference in the other. Glad it helped.